# Is there symbolic date in the world of programming that I can use in snippets/comments?

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style

Programmers often use recurrent values in snippets or comments. For example, in Java

```
String s = "foo";    // recurrent value: "foo"
int i = 42;          // recurrent value: 42
double d = 1337;     // recurrent value: 1337
```

Is there a "metasyntactic value" for a **date**? Or maybe a **symbolic date in the world of programming** typically used in snippets/comments ([Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29), the date of birth of [Alan Turing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing), etc.)?

What date would you choose in the comment of the following Java snippet? `10/01/2013 13:37:42`?

```
// clear the "time part" of a Calendar (10/01/2013 13:37:42 --> 10/01/2013 00:00:00)
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR);
cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

Comment: Metasyntactic variables like `foo`, `bar`, etc. go for date as well as for any other type. Actually that's why they called metasyntactic

Comment: I'm talking about metasyntactic **value**, not metasyntactic **variable**. Maybe not the right word... For a date, let's imagine the Unix epoch (01/01/1970), but there is maybe something more relevant?

Comment: `time(NULL)` seems to be pretty common.

Comment: The Unix epoch is not a good value, as it is an edge case for certain date representations.

Comment: Generally just `new Date()` is used which is the current time.

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar: Seems like a bad idea. OP actually wants an exemplary value, and "today" or "now" are not specific examples.

Comment: @Tinctorius why not? "Today" or "now" seems to be perfect exemplary values for a date to me.

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar In documentation, it would be a *symbolic* value. The whole idea of an example value is that it's a *concrete* value.

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar It seems there is a little bit of confusion. I've updated the question.

Comment: @Tinctorius That's it. You understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the question to: **what is your favourite date/time version of 'foo'?**

I.e. most easily recognized date/time value by most of programmers that could look into your code.

This probably should be also a fun value. Maybe Star Wars premiere 1977.05.25 (but no time), or Back to the Future lightning strike (1955 nov 12 22:04:01?)

There could be dozens or hunderds of proposals, but right now I do not think there is such common date/time value in our heads.

Comment: As [Tinctorius mentionned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255551/is-there-symbolic-date-in-the-world-of-programming-that-i-can-use-in-snippets-co/14806885?iemail=1#comment19799608_14255551), I would choose a date between the [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) and the [32-bit Unix-like time limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). And since I love Back to the Future, [October 21, 2015 4:29 p.m.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_Part_II) seems to be the right choice.